# quantstrat: how to execute on the same bar?

Tags: r, quantstrat

I know that you're not supposed to be doing this but since I almost exclusively trade based on daily and weekly data, I think I'd be getting a more realistic idea of trading ideas if I were able to execute on the same bar instead of buying on next day's open. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `allowMagicalThinking=TRUE` to your call to `applyRules`.  If you add `allowMagicalThinking=TRUE` to your call to `applyStrategy`, it will be passed to `applyRules`.

Comment: This didn't work for me at first when I used `allowMagicalThinking=T`. I guess the lesson is to never use the `T` and `F` abbreviations.